# Capitalizing the first letter of reversed string?JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

- Reverse a sentence.(“How are you?”) to (“You are how?”)

1) How do keep the question mark where it is instead of reversing with "you".

2) How do i make  only the first letter of the sentence capital(You).

this is what i did to reverse by making it to an array first. Is it possible to achieve the above questions by not creating any function?, just for simplicity purpose.

```
var str1 = "how are you?";  document.write(str1.split(" ").reverse().join(" "));
```

Comment: For that one particular sentence, or for more general inputs? Is the input limited to a single sentence? Will it always have exactly one punctuation mark at the end? Can it have embedded punctuation (commas, parentheses, quotation marks, etc.)? You'll need to be more specific about what you need.

Comment: Creating a function would probably have the opposite effect. It would make your code look simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only want to preserve certain punctuation, like any of `.!?`:

```js
function reverseSentences(sentence) {
  return sentence
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(/([.!?]+\s*)/) // split around ending punctuation
    .map(function(part, index) {
      return index % 2 === 0 // even indexes contain sentences, odd is punctuation
        ? capitalize(part.split(' ').reverse().join(' '))
        : part
    })
    .join('');
}

function capitalize(str) {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

console.log(reverseSentences("How are you? That's good."));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a simple function like so

```
function revStr(val, mark) {   
   var qmIdx = val.indexOf(mark);
   var tmp = val.substring(0, qmIdx);
   var rev = tmp.split(" ").reverse().join(" ").toLowerCase();
   return rev.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + rev.slice(1) + mark;
}

revStr("How are you?", "?"); // You are how?
```

Comment: What if it is `!` there instead? What if there are multiple sentences?

Comment: See edited answer. the approach assume a single complete question which should only have one `?`. For multiple sentences, you might have to pass each sentence to the function

Comment: I believe the function must automatically find the punctuation marks. Otherwise the whole task makes very little sense. See the other answer.

Comment: It might be impossible to cover all edge cases. You need to ensure you simplify the problem.

Comment: I'm not an OP. I just pointing you, that the OP has a learning example, and your solution makes very little sense for education purposes.